# Temple Run 2 sync between iPad and iphone?

Tags: temple-run-2

Played since 2010 on iPad and currently level 14. Loaded game on iPhone 7 and only shows level 10 achievement. Have set sync in iCloud, reinstalled. Still not synced.

Anybody else resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, according to questions people made to the developer, sync process may take a few days, you could try signing out from your Apple ID, closing the app, then sign in and finally reopen the app.

**Note that on Temple Run 2, coins and gems are device specific, so that never syncs. What does sync are the stats and unlocks. So if you unlock an upgrade, that WILL SYNC.**

**Also worth mentioning that whether or not in app data such as game progress is saved as part of the backup is up to the developer, but in this case Imangi Studios, [added cloud support](http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/imangi-studios-adds-cloud-syncing-easter-updates-to-temple-run-2/547979) back in 2014.**

If you keep facing problems, I would suggest you contact the developer.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, it’s appreciated